# How to get the integer value from Slot and pass it to another form?

Tags: c++, qt, integer, slot

This is the slot. First form. The sender of integer value. I want to get the value of **selectedInsID** and pass it to the second form.

```
void addteacherform::on_instableView_activated(const QModelIndex &index)
{
    QString val = ui->instableView->model()->data(index).toString();
    dbRepository dr;
    int selectedInsID;

    dr.OpenDBConnection();
    QSqlQuery qry;
    qry.prepare("   SELECT * FROM InstructorTbl WHERE InsFname='"+val+"'  "); // add  or InsFname='"+val+"' for select other col

    if(qry.exec()){
        while(qry.next()){
            selectedInsID=qry.value(0).toInt();
       }
    }
}
```

This is the second form. The receiver of the integer value.

```
void viewhandledsubjectform::on_addHandledSubBtn_clicked()
{
    dbRepository dr;
    addteacherform at;

    dr.OpenDBConnection();
    int row = ui->subjectCodeCombo->currentIndex();
    QModelIndex idx = ui->subjectCodeCombo->model()->index(row, 1); // first column
    QVariant data = ui->subjectCodeCombo->model()->data(idx);

     //Here, I want to get the value of selectedInsID. It is from the first form.


    //insert query
    QSqlQuery qry1;
    qry1.prepare("INSERT INTO InsSubHandleTbl (SubjectCode)"
                "VALUES (:SubjectCode)");
    qry1.bindValue(":SubjectCode",data);


    if(qry1.exec()){
          QMessageBox::information(this,"Added", "Data Added Successfully");
       }
    else{
           qDebug() << "add data failed: " << qry1.lastError();
        }
     dr.CloseDBConnection();
}
```

Comment: How about emitting a signal with that int? Or maybe you want to create an object that 2 functions can access and just update the int into the object in the first slot and then the second slot can access it?

Comment: Can you give me an actual code, because I consider myself as a beginner level. thanks

Comment: Or can you give me an example?

Comment: I can only give you an abstract or general idea cause I don't know your code. Let say you have `Form1`  and `Form2`, they don't know each other, so you need an object that both of them can access. Let called it `globalObject`. Whenever `Form1` do something and you want to update `selectedInsID` for example, you can call `globalObject->update()`. And after that `Form2` can get the updated value with `globalObject->getValue()`. 
Or maybe you can try Mediator: https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/mediator

Comment: The method for the second form seems to be activated with a click. It needs a value from the first form. So, you don't really need a signal/slot mechanism for it. Keep the value somewhere in your first form (a member variable with a getter function). Then call the getter in the second form to obtain the value.

Comment: I created an object. But when i call obj.getText(); the qDebug shows ""